# How to avoid special characters and spaces when update in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a question about SQL Server: how to update target table flag using source table flag in SQL Server based on id and address columns.

When comparing id and address time (source and target tables), we need to consider only character and numbers data only.

While updating time, only consider characters and numbers only no need to consider any spaces or special characters.

Example: source table :

```
id | address            | Flag
1  | 700 N. C Apt J1w02 | 1
```

Target table :

```
id  | address            | Flag
1   | 700 N. C Apt J1w02 |
```

I want to update target table's `Flag` using source table id + address.

Source table address and target table address are same when we are not considering spaces and special character and address is 700NCAptJ1w02
so `Flag` will be updated in target table Flag is :1  similar to others

Output is :  target table :

```
id  | address            | Flag
1   | 700 N. C Apt J1w02 | 1
```

in target table we need to updated only Flag column only.

Another example:

Source table :

```
id     |  address              | Flag
4      | 116 E Spence St #B    | 0
```

Target table :

```
id     | address                                      | Flag 
4      | 11 6 E Sp  enc     e             St #B NULL  |
```

Source table address and target table address are same when we are not considering spaces and special character and address is 116ESpenceStB

Table output record is :

```
id     | address                                          | Flag 
4      | 11  6 E Sp  enc     e             St #B    NULL  | 0
```

Sample table data with script is :

```
---source table : 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sourcemp]
(
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [address] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Flag] [int] NULL
) 

----Target table: we need update flag value using source table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[targetemp]
(
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [address] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Flag] [int] NULL
) 

INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'700 N. C Apt# J1w02', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'7010 N COLTON', 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'0923 E 55th ten-332', 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'9717 E. 6TH AE #32', 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (2, N'5704 E Chattaroy Rd', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (2, N'hen@ye   yte&t#100', 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (2, N'2903 E. Euclid, Apt. #40', 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (3, N'327 1/2 W. 2nd Ave RM SP3', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (3, N'c/o DC!FS   1313 N. Atl*(antic   STE 2000', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (4, N'2706 W. College Ave.', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (4, N'116 E Spence St #B', 0)

GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'700 N. C Apt   J1w02', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'7010 N COLTON.', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'0923 E 55th ten-332', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'971%7    E. 6TH AE #32', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (2, N'5704 E        Chattaroy Rd', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (2, N'henye   yte&t100', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (2, N'2903 E. !Euclid, Apt. #40', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (3, N'327 1/2 W. 2nd Ave RM SP3', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (3, N'c/o DC!FS   1313 N. Atl*anticSTE 2000', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (4, N'2706 WCollege Ave.', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (4, N'11  6 E Sp  enc     e             St #B', NULL)
GO
```

based on above data I want output like below :

```
id  |address                                    Flag
1   |700 N. C Apt   J1w02                           | 1
1   |7010 N COLTON.                                 |0
1   |0923 E 55th ten-332                            |0
1   |971%7    E. 6TH AE #32                         |0
2   |5704 E        Chattaroy Rd                 |1
2   |henye   yte&t100                           |0
2   |2903 E. !Euclid, Apt. #40                  |3
3   |327 1/2 W. 2nd Ave RM SP3                  |1
3   |c/o DC!FS   1313 N. Atl*anticSTE 2000          |2
4   |2706 WCollege Ave.                         |1
4   |11  6 E Sp  enc     e             St #B    |0
```

I tried like below

```
update target   set target.flag=source.flag
from   targetemp target  join sourcemp source 
 on  target.id=source.id and  
 substring (target.address, charindex( ' ', target.address,1),len(target.address))
 =substring (source.address, charindex( ' ', source.address,1),len(source.address))
```

Above query is not returning the expected result.

Please tell me how to write the query to achieve this task in SQL Server.

Comment: `replace` instead of `substring`

Comment: So, let me rephrase that: You have different equivalent representations of an address and while updating you want to match all possible representations. Do not do that! The problem is, that you don't normalize your data before storing it in the DB. There should be only a single valid representation of an address in there so that internal comparisons run fast, easy and reliable. Also, though I'm not sure that's the case, don't put structured strings in the DB. Use the DB itself to represent the structure and not strings that need to be parsed for use then.